# What does Import members from the full Lodash module mean

Tags: javascript, lodash, eslint

```
import _ from 'lodash';

const foo = _.range(3);
```

But ESLint is giving the error "ESLint: Import members from the full Lodash module.(lodash/import-scope)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract only the modules you need to make the code more efficient and semantic like so:

```
import { range } from 'lodash'
```

or

```
import range from 'lodash/range'
```

edited by VLAZ's suggestion.

more info: https://github.com/wix/eslint-plugin-lodash/blob/master/docs/rules/import-scope.md

Comment: That is still going to load the whole module then only extract `range` out of it. It's not exceptionally efficient. `import range from 'lodash/range';` will instead only import that one function.

Comment: So I just tried ````import range from 'lodash/range';```` and its still giving the same ESLint error

Comment: You can use lodash-es  instead.

Comment: @Embedded_Mugs depends on how you've configured your ESLint rule.[`import-scope`](https://github.com/wix/eslint-plugin-lodash/blob/master/docs/rules/import-scope.md) You can choose which should be considered correct or not for your project. As with every single linter rule out there, it's your choice whether to ignore it, change the rule, or change the code to follow the rule.